# How to add a div to poptrox

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, popup

I wondering if there is a method to add text to a poptrox popup. I know I can use the caption attribute to add caption text but that's not what i want. I want to add a div or text element to the pop up it self so when the user clicks on the image, a pop up shows up to describe an image. Is there any why to do this?

I'm following the poptrox github form, I tried using Iframes and the other sources it allows but noting is working the way i want it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML markup for the gallery items, add a div with the class "caption" inside the anchor element that links to the full-size image.

```
<a href="image1.jpg">
    <img src="thumb1.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Caption for Image 1</div>
</a>
```

In the jQuery code that initializes the Poptrox plugin, add the caption class to the list of classes that should be cloned when creating the lightbox.

```
$('.gallery').poptrox({
    caption: function($a) { return $a.next('.caption').text(); },
    overlayColor: '#2c2c2c',
    overlayOpacity: 0.85,
    popupCloserText: '',
    popupLoaderText: '',
    selector: '.thumb > a',
    usePopupCaption: true,
    usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
    usePopupNav: true
});
```

You can then add CSS to style the caption as you desire.

```
.caption {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess there's truly not a way to pass a separate div element. But your answer helped me figure out a work around.